# Digit keyboard confuses the places of the numbers

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
yazı = ' '
root.state('zoomed')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='gray95')
labelsayfa = Entry(root, text='', width=28, font='Calibri 15', bg='dark gray', state='readonly')
c1 = Canvas(width=700, height=650, bg='dark gray')

def b1g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 1)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b2g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 2)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b3g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 3)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b4g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 4)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b5g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 5)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b6g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 6)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b7g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 7)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')
    print(len(str(labelsayfa.get())))

def b8g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 8)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')

def b9g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 9)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')

def b0g():
    labelsayfa.configure(state='normal')
    labelsayfa.insert(len(str(labelsayfa)) + 1, 0)
    labelsayfa.configure(state='readonly')

def bacg():
    labelsayfa.delete(0, END)

def bsilg():
    labelsayfa.delete(len(labelsayfa.get()) - 1, END)

def bokg():
    pass

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='1', width=10, height=5, command=b1g)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='2', width=10, height=5, command=b2g)
b3 = tk.Button(root, text='3', width=10, height=5, command=b3g)
b4 = tk.Button(root, text='4', width=10, height=5, command=b4g)
b5 = tk.Button(root, text='5', width=10, height=5, command=b5g)
b6 = tk.Button(root, text='6', width=10, height=5, command=b6g)
b7 = tk.Button(root, text='7', width=10, height=5, command=b7g)
b8 = tk.Button(root, text='8', width=10, height=5, command=b8g)
b9 = tk.Button(root, text='9', width=10, height=5, command=b9g)
b0 = tk.Button(root, text='0', width=10, height=5, command=b0g)
bac = tk.Button(root, text='AC', width=10, height=5, command=bacg)
bsil = tk.Button(root, text='<--', width=10, height=5, command=bsilg)
bok = tk.Button(root, text='✓', width=39, height=2, command=bokg)

def tag():
    c1.place_forget()

    labelsayfa.place(x=1200, y=100)
    bac.place(x=1200, y=160)
    b1.place(x=1300, y=160)
    b2.place(x=1400, y=160)
    b3.place(x=1200, y=260)
    b4.place(x=1300, y=260)
    b5.place(x=1400, y=260)
    b6.place(x=1200, y=360)
    b7.place(x=1300, y=360)
    b8.place(x=1400, y=360)
    b9.place(x=1200, y=460)
    b0.place(x=1300, y=460)
    bsil.place(x=1400, y=460)
    bok.place(x=1200, y=560)

tag()
root.mainloop()
```

After 5-6 digits the order of the numbers being confused

I want to make a basic digit keyboard but without using keyboard only with buttons

Comment: `len(str(labelsayfa))` returns a completely meaningless number - `str()` of an Entry is going to be the *name* of the widget, and has nothing to do with its contents.  `len(labelsayfa.get())` is closer to what you mean - but you don't actually need a number at all; you can pass `"end"` or `Tk.END` as the index to insert at the end of the Entry.

Comment: Thank you man ı didnt realize this weird error thanks again